# Check if user has MANAGE_MESSAGES permission

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to give a muted role to users that send a message within a channel, however I do not want to issue it to anyone who has the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission.

How can I implement this? Here is my attempt below though it is still giving the muted rule.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  let data = await antilinks.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id });
  if (data.run === 'off') return;
  if (data.run === 'on') {
    if (links(message.content) === true) {
      message.delete()
      try {
        let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(ro => ro.name === 'Muted');
        if (!muterole) {
          message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'Muted',
              color: 'RANDOM',
              permissions: []
            }
          })
        } else {
          message.guild.member(message.author).roles.add(muterole);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if someone has a specific permission using [`hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission).

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  let data = await antilinks.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id });

  // If this user has MANAGE_MESSAGES permission, stop here and do nothing.
  if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return; 

  if (data.run === 'off') return;
  if (data.run === 'on') {
    if (links(message.content) === true) {
      message.delete()
      try {
        let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(ro => ro.name === 'Muted');
        if (!muterole) {
          message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'Muted',
              color: 'RANDOM',
              permissions: []
            }
          })
        } else {
          message.guild.member(message.author).roles.add(muterole);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `message.member.guild.me` returns the client GuildMember, you would need to use `message.member`

Answer (score 1):

**Just incase, you will need to use a new import for this method.**
Import code: `const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');`

**Method:**
For `discord.js` we use the `Permissions` method to check if the user has any roles that has the permissions you set

**Example Code:**

```js
if(message.guild.member(message.author).permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES){
    //code here
}
```

**Your Code:**

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  let data = await antilinks.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id });
  if (data.run === 'off') return;
  if (data.run === 'on') {
    if (links(message.content) === true) {
      message.delete()
      try {
        let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(ro => ro.name === 'Muted');
        if (!muterole) {
          message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'Muted',
              color: 'RANDOM',
              permissions: []
            }
          })
        } else if(message.guild.member(message.author).permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES){
          return;
        } else if(!message.guild.member(message.author).permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES){
          message.guild.member(message.author).roles.add(muterole);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Docs:**
[Permissions | Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#creating-a-role-with-permissions)

Comment: If this helps make sure to click the checkmark saying this answer solved your problem!

Comment: `message.guild.member()` is deprecated. You can just use `message.member`

Comment: Just copied the code that he had from his example.